# Can Ampere's Law be written in terms of magnetization current desnity and polarization current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I know Ampere's Law can be described like:

[image]

I am aware of how to use this law; however, as I was reading through Maxwell's equations I came across magnetization current density and polarization current density. The above law seems to be defined in terms of the electric current density vector, I was wondering how this law would be different if it were to involve magnetization current density or polarization current density vectors?

Can someone please help explain, I really want to ensure a good understanding of this equation and would appreciate the help.

Thank you and sorry for any formatting issues/missing tags, please feel free to edit as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matter (not in vaccuum, as written in your question) the "Ampere-Maxwell" law is $$\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf  J + \frac {\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t} + \epsilon_0 \frac {\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}.$$ Here $\mathbf P$ is the dipole moment density of the material (it is obvioulsy zero in vacuum) and satisfies the "Gauss-Maxwell" equation $\nabla \cdot \mathbf P + \epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \rho $ that are conventionally written with the for the field vector $\mathbf D = \mathbf P + \epsilon_0 \mathbf E$ as
$$\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf  J + \frac {\partial \mathbf D}{\partial t}.$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf D = \rho .$$ In the Ampere-Maxwell law, $ \frac {\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t}$ is the *polarization current* and $\epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \mathbf E $  is the *displacement current*. Regarding "magnetization current", are you talking about this [modification](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/556638/regarding-faradays-law-as-written-in-pozars-microwave-engineering) of Faraday's law? If not then what do you mean by it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, with "magnetization current" I am talking about the modification of Faraday's law which uses magnetic current density I believe. Could this equation be used with magnetic current density, if so I was wondering how it would change?

Comment: If you introduce magnetic currents  in the Faraday law to modify $\nabla \times E$ that does not change the Ampere-Maxwell law for $\nabla \times H$ but you must modify the  $\nabla \cdot B=0$ equation to \nabla \cdot B = \rho_m$ with $\nabla \cdot J _m = -\frac {\rho_m } {\partial t}$ for $B=\mu_0 (M+H)$

Comment: Thank you, got it.